# sudo dpkg --configure -a in a Bash file

Tags: command-line, apt, bash, package-management, dpkg

I have created a bash file to install various packages on the system. I use this script to create a development environment on fresh Ubuntu installation. But sometimes things don't go as expected and the output from bash file asks to run `sudo dpkg --configure -a`.
    Therefore I placed this command at the starting of the script. So that if anything goes wrong this command will set up everything to normal on running the script again.

But it doesn't happen because this command requires interaction with the user as it prompts for yes or no.

Therefore I want 'no' to be entered automatically. As 'yes' is entered in this command `sudo apt-get install apache2 -y`. Therefore I want to know if I can do something like `sudo dpkg --configure -a -n` to reply with 'no' automatically.
I am asking this because I currently don't have any server with broken dpkg. Therefore I can not test if this will work or not. Therefore I asked this question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set a default option for dpkg --configure -a?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/656769/how-to-set-a-default-option-for-dpkg-configure-a)

Comment: Although the question is a duplicate of "How to set a default option for dpkg --configure -a?". But the answer given to this question is not working in my case

Comment: What error(s) are you getting then?

Comment: It says -- dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem

Comment: I have placed "yes N | dpkg --configure -a" at the starting of the bash script

Comment: I want to use the old files

Comment: Look at this https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/324158/160267 example on how you can checked for half installed packages and then run `sudo dpkg --configure -a` use it like this to check `[[ $(dpkg-query -f '${status} ${package}\n' -W | awk '$3 == "installed" {print $4}') ]] || echo "run reconfigure"`