# sudo dpkg-reconfigure wine-stable-amd64 wine-stable wine-stable-i386: Reply Yes automatically

Tags: bash, 20.04, dpkg

To this command:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure wine-stable-amd64 wine-stable wine-stable-i386
```

I want reply "Yes" for three times, without prompt. Such as?

Comment: [How to set a default option](https://askubuntu.com/questions/656769/how-to-set-a-default-option-for-dpkg-configure-a)

Comment: What does "dpkg --configure -a" have to do with "dpkg-reconfigure"?

Comment: [yes](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man1/yes.1.html) | command .... will send y to your command.

Comment: if you want to print "Yes" exact three times you can do `yes Yes | head -n 3 | <your command>`

Comment: Not works......

Comment: sudo -- dpkg-reconfigure -fnoninteractive ...

Comment: another choice is `expect` or  `expect_autoexpect`

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @bac0n. I have solved with:

test.sh

```
#!/bin/bash -e
chmod a+x ./WineHQ-enable-CAP_NET_RAW.exp
sudo ./WineHQ-enable-CAP_NET_RAW.exp
```

WineHQ-enable-CAP_NET_RAW.exp

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
set timeout -1
spawn dpkg-reconfigure --frontend=readline wine-stable-amd64 wine-stable wine-stable-i386
expect "Allow ordinary users to run applications in Wine that send/receive raw IP packets?"
send -- "yes\r"
expect "Allow ordinary users to run applications in Wine that send/receive raw IP packets?"
send -- "yes\r"
expect "Allow ordinary users to run applications in Wine that send/receive raw IP packets?"
send -- "yes\r"
expect eof
```